# what to do with questions that are not useful to users anymore?

Tags: discussion

The question is clear i guess, and i am particularly referring to [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/19997/45659)

Such questions may be of importance for purely historical reasons, but does that mean we live with them around forever?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such questions should be closed as **too localized**. If you don't have the reputation required to vote to close a question (3000) then you can flag the question for moderator attention (with a note explaining why you are flagging it).

To quote from the too localised description (emphasis is mine):

> This question is **unlikely to ever help any future visitors**; it is only
>   relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in time, or an
>   extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally applicable to
>   the worldwide audience of the internet.

Answer (score 7):

Specifically to [When will ratings and review for Ubuntu Software Center start?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19997/) what's wrong with just leaving it as it currently is? It was a valid question at the time of asking, effort was put into answering it and they've picked a good answer as the accepted answer.

Now, what value is there in closing that? It's already dealt with. It has a good answer and that was accepted. It's not attracting crud (meaningless comments/answers). People can understand that it was about a certain time (everything has timestamps on). It's not causing us any problems and closing it won't make any difference.

And as somebody who does occasionally write things, I'm personally interested in how historians are going to perceive us in the next hundred/thousand years. If we went around cleaning up everything that *we* thought was insignificant, I can guarantee that the future's view of us would not be an accurate one.

In short: It's already dealt with, just leave it alone.

The antithesis to this: If you see something mega-old, now irrelevant and *without* answers (of at least +1 score), flag it for deletion.